# Processing a Stream into IAsyncEnumerable - Stream is not readable

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, iasyncenumerable

I have a workflow where I try to do the following:

- A method accepting a callback, which internally produces a `Stream` and the callers of that method can use the callback to process the `Stream` whichever way they want
- In one particular case, the caller is using the callback to produce an `IAsyncEnumerable` from the Stream.

I have created a minimal reproducing example below:

```cs
class Program
{
    private static async Task<Stream> GetStream()
    {
        var text =
            @"Multi-line
            string";

        await Task.Yield();

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        return new MemoryStream(bytes);
    }

    private static async Task<T> StreamData<T>(Func<Stream, T> streamAction)
    {
        await using var stream = await GetStream();
        return streamAction(stream);
    }

    private static async Task StreamData(Func<Stream, Task> streamAction)
    {
        await using var stream = await GetStream();
        await streamAction(stream);
    }

    private static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetTextLinesFromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        while (line != null)
        {
            yield return line;
            line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        }
    }

    private static async Task Test1()
    {
        async Task GetRecords(Stream str)
        {
            await foreach(var line in GetTextLinesFromStream(str))
                Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        await StreamData(GetRecords);
    }

    private static async Task Test2()
    {
        await foreach(var line in await StreamData(GetTextLinesFromStream))
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Test1();
        await Test2();
    }
}
```

Here, method `Test1` works fine, whereas `Test2` does not, failing with `Stream is not readable`. The problem is that in the second case when the code gets to processing the actual stream, the stream is already disposed.

Presumably the difference between the two examples is that for the first one, reading the stream is performed while still in the context of the disposable `stream`, whereas in the second case we are already out.

However, I would argue the second case could be valid too - at least I feel it's quite C#-idiomatic. Is there anything I am missing to get the second case to work too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the `Test2` approach is that the `Stream` is disposed when the `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` is created, not when its enumeration has completed.

The `Test2` method uses the first `StreamData` overload, the one that returns a `Task<T>`. The `T` in this case is an `IAsyncEnumerable<string>`. So the `StreamData` method returns a task that produces an async-sequence, and then immediately disposes the stream (after producing the sequence). Obviously this is not the right moment to dispose the stream. The right moment would be after the `await foreach` loop has completed.

In order to make the `Test2` work transparently, you should add a third overload of the `StreamData` method that returns a `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>` (instead of `Task` or `Task<T>`). This overload should return a specialized asynchronous sequence that is tied to a disposable resource, and disposes this resource when its enumeration has completed. Below is an implementation of such a sequence:

```
public class AsyncEnumerableDisposable<T> : IAsyncEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IAsyncEnumerable<T> _source;
    private readonly IAsyncDisposable _disposable;

    public AsyncEnumerableDisposable(IAsyncEnumerable<T> source,
        IAsyncDisposable disposable)
    {
        // Arguments validation omitted
        _source = source;
        _disposable = disposable;
    }

    async IAsyncEnumerator<T> IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await using (_disposable.ConfigureAwait(false))
            await foreach (var item in _source
                .WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false)) yield return item;
    }
}
```

You could use it in the `StreamData` method like this:

```
private static async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<T>> StreamData<T>(
    Func<Stream, IAsyncEnumerable<T>> streamAction)
{
    var stream = await GetStream();
    return new AsyncEnumerableDisposable<T>(streamAction(stream), stream);
}
```

Bear in mind that in general an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` can be enumerated multiple times during its lifetime, and by wrapping it into an `AsyncEnumerableDisposable<T>` it is essentially reduced to a single-enumeration sequence (because the resource will be disposed after the first enumeration).

---

**Alternative:** The [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) package contains the [`AsyncEnumerableEx.Using`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Using.cs) operator, that can be used instead of the custom `AsyncEnumerableDisposable` class:

```
private static async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<T>> StreamData<T>(
    Func<Stream, IAsyncEnumerable<T>> streamAction)
{
    var stream = await GetStream();
    return AsyncEnumerableEx.Using(() => stream, streamAction);
}
```

The difference is that the `Stream` will be disposed synchronously, via its `Dispose` method. AFAICS there is no support for disposing `IAsyncDisposable`s in this package.

Here is the signature of the `AsyncEnumerableEx.Using` method:

```
// Constructs an async-enumerable sequence that depends on a resource object, whose
// lifetime is tied to the resulting async-enumerable sequence's lifetime.
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Using<TSource, TResource>(
    Func<TResource> resourceFactory,
    Func<TResource, IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>> enumerableFactory)
    where TResource : IDisposable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the suggested solution - I tend to agree this is probably the closest to what I wanted to achieve. Too bad that it requires more specialised overrides for the ```StreamData``` method. 

Anyway, accepting this as the answer.

Comment: @zidour yeah, I don't think that you can get away with only the `Task<T> StreamData<T>(Func<Stream, T> streamAction)` overload. This is too generic, and doesn't provide a mechanism to signal the right time for disposing the `Stream`.